# How do I find the implementation of the abstract method, hasNext()?

Tags: java, oop, collections, interface, polymorphism

I'm confused about the following situation related to Java OOP and Java API/source code arrangement.  Based on [Oracle's Java 8 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), hasNext() is an abstract method, but I couldn't find where hasNext() is implemented.  I read that private inner classes are used to implement different Iterators in each Collection class, but there is no more info about how to find the location of the implementation.  Some users suggested me to add Java JRE 1.8 source code to my Eclipse IDE, but I can only see `boolean hasNext();` declared as an abstract method in the Iterator interface.

As the example shown below, the iterator obj uses hasNext() directly w/o implementing it.  However, I was taught you need to implement an abstract method in an interface.

My Question:
(1) How do I find the implementation of the abstract method, hasNext()? 
(2) A comment says I can find the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#748).  What's the reason to implement hasNext() in ArrayList class, but mark hasNext() as an abstract method? It is not intuitive to find the hasNext() implementation this way.

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("item-1");
    list.add("item-2");
    list.add("item-3");

    Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? In IntelliJ IDEA you can select a method, press CTRL and left mouse click and it takes you straight to the point in the code where the method is written.

Comment: Right here.  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#748

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to ask "Where is *ArrayList's* `Iterator.hasNext()` implemented. If that's the case (you're looking for one implementation in particular) it's helpful to say so in the question.

Comment: if you're using eclipse attach the java source http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-how-to-attach-jdk-source-code/

Comment: I use VIM, but I can download the IDEs mentioned above.  Thanks, guys!

Comment: @LEDFantom Oh, you should *definitely* use an [IDE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Java_IDEs), not a simple text editor like VIM. Using a text editor is like cleaning the floor with a toothbrush. It can be done, but there are much better tools for the job.

Comment: @Andreas   My boss requires me to use VIM to develop and he believes it can do everything. But you are right, IDE is much better.

Comment: In eclipse, you attach java source, open up the interface, caret on the method name or class name, then hit F4, then the "type hierarchy" tab unveils showing all the known implementing classes in a nice tree view.  I suggest you let your boss show you how his VIM can achieve that.  I suppose there will indeed be *some* fancy features to make the development flow smoother, but I won't believe it can ever match all the facilities the professional-grade IDE's have to offer.

Answer (score 3):

You can see in your code, that List is an ArrayList. The method in ArrayList called *iterator()* will return an implementation of Iterator. This implementation of Iterator will have the method *hasNext()* implemented.

It's great to be curious, and as the comment said, you can click into the code in an IDE (or if that doesn't work for you, set a break point in a debugger and step in). Reading the Java code is a great way to de-mystify it.

Of course, you can generally can expect the Java people to know what they are doing, and trust the implementations you get back to be sensible, and fit for general use. The caveat here is that you should also read the documentation. eg. from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator over a collection. Iterator takes the place of Enumeration in the Java Collections Framework. Iterators differ from enumerations in two ways:
Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics.
Method names have been improved.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same question If ListIterator is interface which contains only abstract method which class is responsible for the implementation those methods.

arrived on the conclusion (correct me if I'm wrong)

ArrayList instance method ListIterator is returning instance of ListItr(0)
ListItr(java.util.ArrayList.ListItr) is the class which is implementing the ListIterator interface with the implementation of the abstract methods.
Technically ListIterator can hold instance of it's implementation class.

Answer (score -2):

The `next()` and `hasNext()` methods are part of the `Iterator` interface. Each specific implementation will provide their own versions. You can take a look at how they are defined for the `ArrayListIterator` in the commons-collection library [here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/ArrayListIterator.java/?v=source) or `SingletonListIterator` [here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/SingletonListIterator.java/?v=source).

Comment: Based on "I know that private inner classes are used to implement different Iterators" it looks like OP know that. I suspect that real question is "*how to easily find specific implementation in IDE*".

Comment: I see your point, but I honestly think that an arguably wrong formulation of the question shouldn't lead to a downvote on a somewhat valid answer to: `My Question: Where is the abstract method, hasNext(), implemented? How do I find it?`

Comment: Agree, that is why I didn't downvote you (but can't stop others from doing so and can't upvote you because I am not sure if it properly answers OP question).

Comment: I read it in some thread not on stackoverflow about iterators have inner classes to implement some methods w/ no more explanations.  And as I noted, I'm also trying to understand the OOP relationship of Java.  So @Pshemo, your comment only answered half of my question.

Comment: The question was "how to find *implementation*", so an answer that say "read the javadoc of the *interface*" is extremely meaningless to the question, because that will just give you the specification, not the implementation.

Comment: @Andreas It is not the best answer of the world, agreed, but my intention was clearly misinterpreted. I pointed to `Iterator` as the abstraction and `ListIterator` as concrete implementation.

Comment: @DavidFernandez `ListIterator` is not a concrete implementation given that it is just a sub-*interface*. There is no implementation there, which is the point of my comment: Question is about implementations and your post tells to go look at interfaces. That's not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, you are completely right, I just got it wrong with a base interface and a subinterface instead of an implementation. I updated my answer with a couple of examples of iterators in case someone wants a quick example.

Comment: @Andreas, the javadoc includes a section titled "all known implementing classes".  Seems like ***exactly*** the answer to "how to find implementation".